# I am capturing image by this code and i have to record video also how to do that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

**I am capturing image by this code but i have to record the video also on clicking the button and save it so please tell me what should i do? actually i am not getting because i have successfully captured the image and save it to my photo album but now i have to record video also and store it so please any one give me better idea for it **

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
   front=NO;
   self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
barPicker.value = hue;
    pickerArr=[[NSArray   alloc]initWithObjects:@"01",@"02",@"03",@"04",@"05",@"06",@"07",@"08",@"09",@"10", nil];
   flashlightOn=YES;
  [flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [camraButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camra.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
 [self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
[self.vImagePreview addSubview:flashButton];
[self.vImagePreview addSubview:camraButton];
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
 NSError *error = nil;
input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:  AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
 if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
else
{
    [session addInput:input];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

}
[session startRunning];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
    -(IBAction) captureNow
 {

if (!front)
{
    if (flashlightOn) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device1 = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([device1 hasTorch] && [device1 hasFlash])
        {
            [device1 lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device1 setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device1 setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
            [device1 unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput. connections) {
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) {
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection                                completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)

 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments) {

     }
     else {
     }
     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

     image.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    }];

  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry I can't edit your code but i am providing some links that will help you to achieve your task..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_6_iPhone_Camera_Application

just check out these links..

Enjoy..

Comment: This meta discussion on why it's not helpful to post an answer that only includes links to other resources is a good read. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers